# USPS HTTP Post Request

Tags: perl, http

Here is the error message I am receiving when I try to run the following Perl code. Any ideas what causing this? It appears it does not like the API=Verify, but it was the only name for the API which returns a 9 digit zip code I could find.

80040B1AAPI Authorization failure. is not a valid API name for this 
protocol.USPSCOM::DoAuth

```
# Perl subroutine for POST Request
#########
sub FindTracking() {
$saddress="60 Passional Way";
$scity="Burnsville";
$szip="27690";
$sstate="NC";
print "start of tracking...<br>";

$queryString = qq~
<?xml version="1.0"?>
https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=        
<AddressValidateRequest USERID="xxxxxxx">
<Revision>1</Revision>
<Address ID="0">
<Address1></Address1>
<Address2>$saddress</Address2>
<City>$scity</City>
<State>$sstate</State>
<Zip5>$szip</Zip5>
<Zip4></Zip4>
</Address>
</AddressValidateRequest>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AddressValidateResponse><Address ID="0">
<Address2></Address2><City></City><State></State><Zip5></Zip5>
<Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateResponse>
<Error>
<Number></Number>
<Source></Source>
<Description></Description>
<HelpFile></HelpFile>
<HelpContext></HelpContext>
</Error>
~;

# Instantiate the user agent and set our agent string
$userAgent = new LWP::UserAgent;
$userAgent->agent( 'USPS' );
$queryString =~ s/ /\%20/ig;
$request = new HTTP::Request( 'POST',      
'https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll' );

# Set the content type
$request->content_type( 'text/xml' );

# Set the query string
$request->content( $queryString );

# Make the request
$response = $userAgent->request( $request );
print $response->content();
# Check the status of the request
if ( $response->is_success ) {
    $content = $$response{ "_content" };
  $TrackingNumber = "";
  ($success) = $content =~ /\<AddressValidateRequest\>(.*)\    
 <\/AddressValidateRequest\>/;
  print "<br><br>==>some $content<br>";
  if ($success eq "Success") {
    ($TrackingNumber)= $content =~ /\<Zip4\>(.*)\<\/Zip4\>/;
   print "here with $TrackingNumber<br>";
   }

}
else {
  print "<br><br>here with resp=$response<br>req=$request <br>cont     
$content";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query XML to:

```
$queryString = qq~
<AddressValidateRequest USERID="xxxxxxxxxxx">
<Revision>1</Revision>
  <Address ID="0">
    <Address1></Address1>
    <Address2>$saddress</Address2>
    <City>$scity</City>
    <State>$sstate</State>
    <Zip5>$szip</Zip5>
    <Zip4></Zip4>
  </Address>
</AddressValidateRequest>
~;
```

Then build the request as a GET instead of a POST:

```
$userAgent = new LWP::UserAgent;
$userAgent->agent( 'USPS' );
$url = "https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=$queryString";

$request = new HTTP::Request( 'GET',  $url );
```

Answer (score 1):

To start, you have an invalid query string. Compare what you are doing to the [USPS WebTools example](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.htm) and remove what they don't show. Be sure that you are setting your USERID properly (and not using 'xxxxxxx'); an environment variable is handy there.

Or, you can try using the [Business::USPS::WebTools](https://github.com/CPAN-Adoptable-Modules/business-us-usps-webtools) module from GitHub. It implements the Zip Code Lookup.

Comment: I am using my proper ID. Can you tell me where the query string is invalid?